# Android - Split action bar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change color of split action bar (bottom bar), so I tried `actionBar.setSplitBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));` but the problem is that my API is 11 and minimum API for this function is 14. Even I tried to change the color in `style.xml` by `<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/blue</item>` but the same problem occurred. any suggestion?

Comment: You can't change the API level to 14?

Comment: Use SherlockActionBar

Comment: I can not choose higher API but I saw apps with API 11 doing this without custom action bar

Comment: If you try this `ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0000ff")));` does it work?

Comment: @JoanColmenero: no, there is no diffrence